# When exactly would a Calloutexception occurs in Salesforce?

Tags: integration, callout, exception, xml, apexrest

I am trying to send a XML from Salesforce to an external system and callout exception occurs time and again . It is occurring sometime but working fine most of the times . What are the cases when a callout exception would ideally occur?

Comment: n.b. - when faced with intermittent callout exception, I ended up building retry logic (my example was REST GET query but principle applies)

Answer (score 0):

Some scenarios where callout exception occours:

- Network issues
- external server not responding(Any issue fro server not available to server overload)
- invalid request format(Sometimes...)

A lot to go in the list...

Comment: Invalid Request Format will not generate callout exception directly . It will generate 401 error after failing XSD validations .